# Bash "if" statement not working properly

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to run this command in shell, but the output is clearly wrong.

```
day=$(date -r myfile.c | cut -d ' ' -f 1); if(($day == "Fri")); then echo $day; fi;
```

And the output is `Sat`. How is this possible?
I already tried different way:

```
if(($day == "Fri"))
if(("$day" == "Fri"))
if(("$day" == 'Fri'))
```

Comment: Search google for the correct bash `if` syntax, or run `man test`.

Comment: Yeah; `if [ $day = "Fri" ] then ...`

Comment: With square brakets I get syntax error

Comment: The spaces are required. `[` is an actual command; `$day`, `=`, `"Fri"`, and `]` are arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax that you're using to do string comparison is incorrect.

The portable syntax is `if [ "$day" = Fri ]`.

The bash-specific syntax would be `if [[ $day = Fri ]]` - with `[[`, the quotes aren't needed.

Note that spaces between keywords/commands are important, so you can't write `if[`, because the shell doesn't know what `if[` refers to.

Comment: Also, `(( ))` are for arithmetic, not text, comparisons.